# IE9 has problems with HTML5 Canvas getImageData() function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, internet-explorer-9, getimagedata

For some reason the below code will not work. It stops at the line with `getImageData`. IE9 throws this error: `SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INDEX_SIZE_ERR (1)`. Is there a workaround to solve this? However, it works in both Chrome and FF.

```
//Select our canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//Select the image from the DOM
var selectedImage = document.getElementById("image");

//Draw the image to the canvas then read in the data
context.drawImage(selectedImage, 0, 0);
var originalLakeImageData = context.getImageData(0,0, width, height);

//Image data is now stored in an array in the form
//originalLakeImageData.data = [r1, g1, b1, a1, r2, g2, b2, a2....]
```

*Note: The above code isn't my code. The source is [here](http://nooshu.com/using-image-data-inside-the-html5-canvas-element). However, my problem is identical to this example. To see the error IE9, try this [link](http://nooshu.com/explore/canvas-image-data/)*

Comment: What is the value of `width` and `height` at the time the error occurs?

Comment: The width and height at the time is 0 - just looked up in the debugger. Maybe you can find a hint here: http://jimdiesel.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/javasvript-image-dimension-issue-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Just came across your question while searching for another  question. The problem you are encountering has to do with the fact that the `oldImage` is set to `display: none` in your CSS. This causes the `width` and `height` attributes to be zero.

You should try using `visibility: hidden`. CSS `display:none` means that the element should not be displayed at all, but `visibility:hidden` means that the element(s) are there but just not visible. It is a slight difference, but should make your example work.

You could also use absolute positioning and z-index to 'hide' the other images behind the one you want to see.